# Crystal Reports Subreport Grouping

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

This Question is regarding crystal reports sub-report grouping
I have around 10 sub-reports each report is linked with One table(which is also sub report).

Table1

```
EMPID EmpName EmpSal EmpDesg
1     srik    12222  sssss
2     sri     22222  aaaaa
3     sss     3333   dddd
```

Table2

```
EMPID  Accontno  BankName  Bal
1      234444     HDFC     12
2      5555555    ABC       1
3      333333     jjj       1
```

Table3

```
EMPID  PrevOrg  Loc    EXp
1      ssss     Bang     2
2      ABC      Cal      3   
3      BCD      HYd      5
```

I have 7 more tables with foreign key EMPID.  Each Table I have designed as sub-report.

Now I want to show my report in such a way that all EMPID 1 records at one place followed EMPID 2 records ....

Expected O/P:leave about headings

```
1     srik    12222  sssss(Table1)
1     234444  HDFC     12(Table2)
1     ssss     Bang     2(Table3)

2     sri       22222      aaaaa (Table1)
2     5555555    ABC       1     (Table2)
2     BC         Cal       3     (Table3)

3      sss       3333    dddd  (Table1)
3      333333    jjj       1   (Table2)
3      BCD       HYd      5   (Table3)
```

How to group the tables from different sub-reports in  above format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add Table 1 to the main report.
2. Delete the sub-report that contains Table 1 (you won't need it)
3. Add the relevant fields from Table 1 to the Details section of the main report
4. Add a Details section (insert section below) for each of the remaining sub-reports.  Section
   Details A will contain the fields that you added in step 3.  Details B..Details J will contain each of the remain sub-reports (one in each section)
5. Link the EMPID in the main report to the EMPID in each of the subreports
6. Insert a group in the main report on EMPID

Comment: Hi Craig,5.Link the EMPID in the main report to the EMPID in each of the subreports   You mean Link the Tables Uisng Data Source->Liks or some other approach.Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much craig solution is working

Small info before closing thread
To link sub report to main link follow the steps below:

Right click on Subreport
select "Change Subreport Links"
opens dialog from the Diaglog Move the common filed in my case "EMPID" from "Available fields" ->"Filed(s) To link To:

Dont change any thing else except this.