# Crystal Reports Subreport Grouping with multi same fields

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

This Question is regarding crystal reports sub-report grouping I have 2 sub-reports each report is linked with One table(which is also sub report).

Table1 (input)

| ProductCode | BatchCode | Date | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1221000 | 1221000-1125-001 | 2020-01-12 | 10 |
| 1221000 | 1221000-1125-002 | 2020-01-14 | 15 |
| 1221000 | 1221000-1125-003 | 2020-01-18 | 02 |
| 1556000 | 1556000-0255-012 | 2020-03-20 | 8 |

Table2 (ouput)

| ProductCode | BatchCode | Date | Qty | BL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1221000 | 1221000-1125-001 | 2020-01-12 | 3 | 06 |
| 1221000 | 1221000-1125-002 | 2020-01-14 | 2 | 08 |
| 1556000 | 1556000-0255-012 | 2020-06-20 | 2 | 02 |
| 1556000 | 1556000-0255-012 | 2020-06-23 | 2 | 01 |
| 1556000 | 1556000-0255-022 | 2020-07-28 | 2 | 01 |

Now I want to show my report in such a way that all ProductCode 1 records at one place followed ProductCode 2 records ....

As below:

ProductCode: 1221000

| ProductCode | BatchCode | Date | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1221000 | 1221000-1125-001 | 2020-01-12 | 10 |
| 1221000 | 1221000-1125-002 | 2020-01-14 | 15 |
| 1221000 | 1221000-1125-003 | 2020-01-18 | 02 |

| ProductCode | BatchCode | Date | Qty | BL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1221000 | 1221000-1125-001 | 2020-01-12 | 3 | 06 |
| 1221000 | 1221000-1125-002 | 2020-01-14 | 2 | 08 |

ProductCode: 1556000

| ProductCode | BatchCode | Date | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1556000 | 1556000-0255-012 | 2020-03-20 | 8 |

| ProductCode | BatchCode | Date | Qty | BL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1556000 | 1556000-0255-012 | 2020-06-20 | 2 | 02 |
| 1556000 | 1556000-0255-012 | 2020-06-23 | 2 | 01 |
| 1556000 | 1556000-0255-022 | 2020-07-28 | 2 | 01 |

How to group the tables from different sub-reports in above format. I mean display (Input/output) for each ProductCode or grouped by ProductCode.

Thanks :)

Note: I saw the answer [Crystal Reports Subreport Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454565/crystal-reports-subreport-grouping?newreg=073390ecb1f24b6f812e3839b08a16c5)

But it doesn't work for my case.